# Seam or any other IoC in Jboss-ESB

Tags: seam, ioc-container, jboss-esb

Is there any IoC in Jboss-ESB?

Im trying to hack an annotated ESB action using org.jboss.soa.esb.actions.annotation.Process annotation.

Having some external dependencies I would like to use some IoC for the purpose of TDD. seam is of cause not part off the runtime (that’s web stuff). Is there any or am I barking at the moon?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK Seam is not supported.

For IOC there is some Spring support. What you have out of the box is the AbstractSpringAction where you can have your action call Spring beans which you declare in the Spring application context provided in the configuration of the action:

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossesb/docs/4.4.GA/javadoc/esb/org/jboss/soa/esb/actions/AbstractSpringAction.html

This is pretty limited since you would have a separate application context for each such action.

This post suggests an approach that can work around this problem and create a global application context by implementing a custom ContextLoader for JBoss ESB:

http://duncandoyle.blogspot.se/2012/02/autowiring-your-jboss-esb-actions-with.html

Have not tried it myself but it looks promising.